# Servicestack with a Java client

Tags: java, rest, servicestack

i've implemented some web services with service stack (btw: i'm absolutely in love with servicestack!). The strongly typed clients for the .NET world are great! There is a new client coming which wants to access the services with java.

SS suggests to provide a native api. Is there a way to convert the POCO to POJO so Java clients have the same strongly typed experience as .NET? It sounds a little bit lazy but is there a way/format/whatever to automate or make this process less manual?

Another thing i'm thinking is to allow also SOAP. The REST/XML/JSON stuff works awesome in servicestack, but I've no experiences in hosting SOAP services with servicestack. As far as i know is that not everything from soap is implemented, but it's difficult to see where the "line" is or which features are not working.

edit:
as mentioned in the comment, the question(s) are not clear:

1. what is the easiest way to create the java clients for the SS services?
2. has anybody experiences (production) in using servicestack for SOAP?

Comment: and what is the question?

Comment: I haven't tried this, and it's a bit roundabout, but theoretically you could integrate the [ServiceStack Swagger interface](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Swagger-API) with your service and then use [Swagger Codegen](https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-codegen) to generate Java client classes.

Comment: @esker: yes i'm using swagger, thanks for this link, i'll try that! but i'm still open for other suggestions.

Comment: @marco forberg: sorry, i've added 2 question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way of calling ServiceStack Services from Java clients is to use the built-in [Java Add ServiceStack Reference](http://docs.servicestack.net/java-add-servicestack-reference) support.

Comment: In the meantime, this is pretty clear :) but i forgot that this question exists. Anyway thx :)

Comment: @unreal np was just doing some unanswered questions cleaning :)